# Problem while scraping twitter using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

problem while scraping a heavy website like Facebook or twitter with lot of html tags using beautiful soup and requests library.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 

html_text = requests.get('https://twitter.com/elonmusk').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
elon_tweet = soup.find_all('span', class_='css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0')
print(elon_tweet)
```

[The tweet and its corresponding span](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioPbb.jpg)

The full span image

[img link to the span](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szm4M.png)

when the code is executed this returns a empty list.

I'm new to web scraping, a detailed explanation would be welcomed.

Comment: Use the Twitter API with a module like [`twitter`](https://pypi.org/project/twitter/) or [`tweepy`](https://pypi.org/project/tweepy/). Much much easier than trying to scrape a dynamically-generated page...

Comment: ok first of all thanks for the tip but I cant understand what is the bug in the above code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is that twitter is loading its content dynamically. This means that when you make a request, the page is loaded and first returns the html from here (write in your browser's address bar: "view-source:[https://twitter.com/elonmusk"](https://twitter.com/elonmusk%22))

Later, after the page is loaded, the JavaScript is executed and adds the full content of the page.
With requests from python you can only scrape the content available on "view-source:[https://twitter.com/elonmusk"](https://twitter.com/elonmusk%22), and as you can see, the element that you're trying to scrape it's not there.

To scrape this element you will need to use selenium, which allows you to emulate a browser directly from python, and therefore wait the few extra needed seconds so that the whole content will be loaded. You can find a good guide on this over here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-2/

Also if you don't want all this trouble, you can use instead an API that allows JavaScript rendering.