# Why wont BeautifulSoup extract all the HTML from a public twitter page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, twitter

I am trying to write some code to extract tweets from a public  twitter page (Nike store) using the Python BS4 module. When I print the page HTML into the console, only some of the HTML is printed -  when I try to search (ctrl +F) the specific class values for a tag from the console output and it returns with zero results. Why is this happening?

Here a code snippet:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

from urllib.request import urlopen

import re

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Read webpage into page_html' and close connection to webpage'
    first_page = 'https://twitter.com/nikestore'
    url_client = urlopen(first_page)
    page_html = url_client.read()
    url_client.close()
    print(page_html)
```

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54883608/how-twitter-hides-their-html-or-attributes-in-view-page-source-ctrl-u).

Comment: Because `bs4` **doesn't** run JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks for this, I followed other linked and augmented my search and came across this. The accepted answer is what I was looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987825/problem-while-scraping-twitter-using-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 0):

I came across the accepted answer in the following link. Answer also suggests using selenium to circumvent the problem.

[Problem while scraping twitter using beautiful soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987825/problem-while-scraping-twitter-using-beautiful-soup)